# What is the significance of Sherlock's dream?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock

In the episode, A scandal in Belgravia, the woman drugs Sherlock in her apartment. In the drugged condition, it was shown that Sherlock solved the death of the hiker. Now the solution in his dream was unfolded by a friendly discussion with the woman.

We see Sherlock takes too much interest in the woman after recovering from the trauma. So what does the dream mean? Did Sherlock explain the mystery to the woman in the drugged condition? Or the woman whispered the explanation to Sherlock's ears when he was dizzy?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as i remember it wasn't a dream. I believe it was a conversation they had when he was in that drugged condition which is why it was shown as being in a dream and I know it wasn't a dream because she returns Sherlock's coat with him along with her phone inside it.

She also figures out that how Sherlock took one glance to figure out how that guy who died mysteriously when he was fishing earlier in that episode was in fact killed by his boomerang.